# How do you change an expired certificate?

Tags: macos, certificate

While I've been using mac for sometime. Often when I'm doing software updates on various machines I need to install new software. Most updates have certificates which are sometimes out of date.

I remember a colleague mentioned to me there's a way to change that and make a certificate valid, with out having to go through the rigmarole of downloading a fresh copy of that particular file.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You can't make the expired certificate valid unless you disconnect your Mac from network and change the date backward. But as soon as you connect to the network the certification validation software most likely detects it again.